# How to update data in database that have the same parent_id?

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

I have two tables which is parent_table and child table like below

table_parent > primary key is `id`

```
id       Month    emp_no                
------  -------   -------                
1       Jan       2345                   
2       Apr       5678
```

table_child  > primary key is `id`. `parent_id` is the primary key which is `id` from the `table_parent`

```
id      parent_id        type                
------ -----------       --------------------                 
1      1                 GIFT                                   
2      1                 FOOD REFRESHMENT  
3      1                 TRANSPORT
4      2                 GIFT
5      2                 TRANSPORT
```

Stored procedure with the select: this stored procedure is to load data into gridview using VB.Net.

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `test1`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `SP_SELECT`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`testing1`@`%` PROCEDURE `SP_SELECT`(
    IN _parent_id INT
)
BEGIN
    
SELECT type
FROM table_child 
WHERE parent_id = _parent_id ;
 
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Stored procedure with the `UPDATE` to update data in table_child:

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `test1`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `SP_UPDATE`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`testing1`@`%` PROCEDURE `SP_UPDATE`(
    IN _parent_id INT,
    IN _type VARCHAR(50)
)
BEGIN
    
UPDATE table_child 
SET type = _type
WHERE parent_id = _parent_id 
 
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

The problem here, if in where clause for update I only use `WHERE parent_id = _parent_id` it'll update ALL the data that have the SAME parent_id. and if I use `WHERE parent_id = _parent_id AND id = _id` it'll update only the first row. Any idea how can I fix this ?

Comment: Please clarify what you need, since your question sounds like *How to update data in database that have the same parent_id?* and you wrote *if in where clause for update I only use WHERE parent_id = _parent_id it'll update ALL the data that have the SAME parent_id*

Comment: Either you want to update all the records with the same `parent_id` or you don't. If you do, specify just that `parent_id`. If you don't, don't specify the `parent_id` at all. Specify the `id` of the record(s) you want to update.

Comment: Ah, I change the where clause from `WHERE parent_id = _parent_id` to `WHERE id = _id` and it works fine. It was dumb of me.